# "Clean" an array inside another array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm currently struggling with a task, hope somebody can guide me in the right direction.

I have this array:

```
const data = [
{
  year: 2021,
  data: [
    { month: 'Jan', amount: 5000000 },
    { month: 'Feb', amount: 3500000 },
    { month: 'Mar', amount: 15000000 },
    { month: 'Apr', amount: 5000000},
    { month: 'May', amount: 3500000 },
    { month: 'Jun', amount: 15000000 },
    { month: 'Jul', amount: 13000000 },
    { month: 'Aug', amount: 20000000 }
  ]
},
{
  year: 2020,
  data: [
    { month: 'Jan', amount: 5000000 },
    { month: 'Feb', amount: 3500000 },
    { month: 'Mar', amount: 15000000 },
    { month: 'Apr', amount: 5000000},
    { month: 'May', amount: 3500000 },
    { month: 'Jun', amount: 15000000 },
    { month: 'Jul', amount: 13000000 },
    { month: 'Aug', amount: 20000000 }
  ]
}
```

]

And I'm trying to clean this so I can use HighCharts JS, which needs the following structure:

```
const data = [
  { year: '2021',
    data: [5000000, 3500000, 15000000, 5000000, 3500000, 15000000, 13000000, 20000000 ]
  },
  { year: '2020',
    data: [5000000, 3500000, 15000000, 5000000, 3500000, 15000000, 13000000, 20000000 ]
  }
]
```

So basically, is to clean the data array inside each object to get only the amount value without the month name. I tried doing a map and storage the result in a useState (I'm working with React JS) with no success.

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
data.map(({ year, data: innerData }) => ({
   year,
   data: innerData.map(({ amount }) => amount)
}))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and very easy to read. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can map each object and replace the data array with a mapped data array inside a `{...}` spread

```js
const data = [
{
  year: 2021,
  data: [
    { month: 'Jan', amount: 5000000 },
    { month: 'Feb', amount: 3500000 },
    { month: 'Mar', amount: 15000000 },
    { month: 'Apr', amount: 5000000},
    { month: 'May', amount: 3500000 },
    { month: 'Jun', amount: 15000000 },
    { month: 'Jul', amount: 13000000 },
    { month: 'Aug', amount: 20000000 }
  ]
},
{
  year: 2020,
  data: [
    { month: 'Jan', amount: 5000000 },
    { month: 'Feb', amount: 3500000 },
    { month: 'Mar', amount: 15000000 },
    { month: 'Apr', amount: 5000000},
    { month: 'May', amount: 3500000 },
    { month: 'Jun', amount: 15000000 },
    { month: 'Jul', amount: 13000000 },
    { month: 'Aug', amount: 20000000 }
  ]
}]

const newdata = data.map(e=> ({...e, data: e.data.map(x=>x.amount)}))
console.log(newdata)
```